# Create sequence of squares centered

Tags: python

Im trying to create a sequence of squares with each square centered. I wrote code to offset the pen position by (5, -5) but was not able to center the squares.

```
def drawSquareSequance(myTurtle, maxSide, minSide):
    for sidelength in range(maxSide, minSide, -5):
        for square in range(4):
          myTurtle.forward(sidelength)
          myTurtle.right(90)
        for newPos in range(1, 10, -5):
            myTurtle.penup()
            myTurtle.setposition(newPos, newPos) #trying to place coordinates here
            myTurtle.pendown()
```

drawSquareSequance(t,150,100)

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Note that `range(1, 10, -5)` is empty...

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: If 3th argument of `range` is negative, it assumes backward order: `range(10, 1, -5)` makes `[10, 5]` sequence, but `range(1, 10, -5)` makes empty sequence.